# Sending keydown to Angular directive with jQuery .trigger()

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've created an edit directive to wrap an html input in a fancy frame.

Now I'm creating a unit test to check that once I type in the input the dirty state of the form controller is set.

I'm using jQuery.trigger() to simulate this, but I get nothing...

```
var input = $('input');
var e = $.Event('keydown');
e.which = 'x'.charCodeAt(0);
e.keyCode = 'x'.charCodeAt(0);
input[0].focus();
input.trigger(e);
```

I have a plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/oeZeyq2i0KEPcyvGqWqT?p=preview)

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10685520/trigger-the-jquerys-keypress-event-on-an-input-text/10685653#10685653) to a similar question:

> The mistake you're making is what you're expecting the jQuery's
>   trigger method to do. If you check out the code you'll see that what
>   it is doing is actually executing the jQuery registered event handlers
>   not the DOM Level 3 events. Because it's only executing jQuery
>   handlers you wont be causing the change event which is what you need
>   to be triggered to update the value property of the textbox.

Instead you can update the input's value and trigger the change or the input event:

```
input.val('x').trigger('input');
```

When doing this inside a controller in a live application however (as opposed to in the unit test environment), you need to break out of the $digest cycle, or you will get the `$apply already in progress` error.

You can do this by for example using `setTimeout`:

```
$scope.trigger = function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('input').val('x').trigger('input');
  });
};
```

You also need to make sure that you are loading jQuery before AngularJS. If you don't, Angular will use jqLite instead. jqLite uses `addEventHandler` to register event handlers, and handlers registered this way don't get triggered by jQuery's `trigger` function.

**Demo of your code updated:** http://plnkr.co/edit/u3ZWXWLvOjbKWlY8JEM5?p=preview

When unit testing:

```
it('should work', function() {

  var element = $compile('<form name="form"><edit ng-model="name"></edit></form>')($scope);
  $rootScope.$digest();

  var scope = element.scope(),
    form = scope.form,
    input = element.find('input');

  expect(form.$dirty).toBe(false);

  input.val('x').trigger('input');

  expect(form.$dirty).toBe(true);
});
```

**Demo of the unit test:** http://plnkr.co/edit/Emc3dIlDaxXyE9U6dEG6?p=preview

Comment: ow man, I can't thank you enough for coming up with the `trigger('input')` part. I tried other things like `keyup` and so forth but nothing worked... Thank you so very much