# Angular directives: It's possible testing that certain characters are rejected in a keypress event?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, jasmine, angular-directive

I've been building a directive that restricts a user from pressing certain invalid characters, in this case, using the `keypress` event binding to the input element that uses my directive.
I've been trying to test this functionality, but i don't understand how to achieve this.

My directive

```
angular
    .module('gp.rutValidator')
    .directive('gpRutValidator', directive);

  directive.$inject = ['$filter'];

  function directive($filter){
    var ddo = {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: linkFn
    };
    return ddo;

    function linkFn(scope, element, attrs, ngModel){

      //valid characters are digits, dash and letter k
      var regexValidKeys = (/[\d\.\-k]/i);

      element.bind('keypress', function(e){

        var key = e.key || String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);

        if (!regexValidKeys.test(key)) {
          e.preventDefault();
          return false;
        }

      });

    }
  }
```

My test

```
describe('Angular Rut Validator Directive',validatorDirectiveSpec);

  function validatorDirectiveSpec(){

    //////////////  GLOBALS   ////////////////////////////////
    var scope, element, evt;
    //////////////  BEFORE EACH ////////////////////////////////
    beforeEach(module('gp.rutValidator'));
    beforeEach(inject(eachSpec));

    function eachSpec($rootScope, $compile){
      element = angular.element('<input ng-model="rut" gp-rut-validator>');
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      $compile(element)(scope);
      scope.$digest();
    }

    ////////////////// HELPERS ///////////////////////////////////
    function pressKey(keyCode) {
      try {
        // Chrome, Safari, Firefox
        evt = new KeyboardEvent('keypress');
        delete evt.keyCode;
        Object.defineProperty(evt, 'keyCode', {'value': keyCode});
      }
      catch (e) {
        // PhantomJS 
        evt = document.createEvent('Events');
        evt.initEvent('keypress', true, true);
        evt.keyCode = keyCode;
      }
      element[0].dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
    //////////////////   SPECS //////////////////////////////////
    it('1. Should be reject no valid characters', spec1);

    function spec1(){
      var ngModelCtrl = element.controller('ngModel'),
          invalidCharacterKeys = [
                                    'a'.charCodeAt(0),
                                    'z'.charCodeAt(0),
                                    'b'.charCodeAt(0),
                                    '#'.charCodeAt(0)
                                  ];

      invalidCharacterKeys.forEach(function(keyCode){
        pressKey(keyCode);
        scope.$digest();
        expect(scope.rut).toBe('');
      });

    }

  }
```

But I get the error `Expected undefined to be ''.`

**What am I doing wrong?**

Example in Codepen => http://codepen.io/gpincheiraa/pen/ozWyvA

Comment: Haven't tried myself, but some quick digging seems to have found an answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23561259/sending-keydown-to-angular-directive-with-jquery-trigger

Comment: Thanks, this technique looks awesome!

Answer (score 1):

How about replacing the Event.prototye.preventDefault:

```
var original = Event.prototype.preventDefault;
Event.prototype.preventDefault = function(){
    original.bind(this);
    handlers.filter((handler) => handler.keyCode == this.keyCode).forEach((handler)=>handler.handle(this));
    handlers = handlers.filter((handler)=> handler.keyCode != this.keyCode);
}
```

and make him call a predefined Callback:

```
function pressKey(keyCode, cb) {
        try {
            // Chrome, Safari, Firefox
            handlers.push({keyCode : keyCode, handle: cb});
            evt = new KeyboardEvent('keypress');
            delete evt.keyCode;
            Object.defineProperty(evt, 'keyCode', {'value': keyCode});
            element[0].dispatchEvent(evt);
        }
        catch (e) {
            // PhantomJS 
            evt = document.createEvent('Events');
            evt.initEvent('keypress', true, true);
            evt.keyCode = keyCode;
            element[0].dispatchEvent(evt);
        }
    }
```

and then call pressKey like this:

```
pressKey(keyCode, (event)=>{expect(event.keyCode).toBe(keyCode)}));
```

I am not 100% sure if this is what you've asked for...

Answer (score 0):

Use this code  `it('1. Should be reject not valid characters')` instead of   `it('1. Should be reject no valid characters', spec1);`

Comment: why i should be use this way?

Comment: Actually what kind of message you need to show give me an exmple

Comment: If I use `pressKey(keyCode)` I expect that scope.rut (the variable passed as model on the directive in the compiled html element) should be `''`

Answer (score 0):

How about extracting logic out of the infrastructural / low level code, and testing it in a clearer way?

In other words, define a service which takes key as an input, and then returns `true/false` result. Service does not listen to the html element's event, it just takes input and gives output. So, you can test this service (as any other service) using your jasmine unit-tests. Then, inject this service into your directive and call it from the event handler (binding still happens inside directive). If the service returns false, also call `e.preventDefault()`, otherwise allow the key.

Obviously, this approach will not test how you are subscribing to the html element's event (bind), but I don't think that's your intention at all. This will test which keys are accepted/denied just fine, by following the cleaner separation of concerns - this is *MVC* after all, which is all about separating concerns.